# How to force Authorize.net Directpost reply_url to be HTTPS?

Tags: magento, authorize.net, dpm

I'm trying to enable the Authorize.net DPM (Direct Post Method) on a Magento 1.11.1 production site. My test site (also Magento 1.11.1.0) works fine because the site is not secure (frontend SSL), but the live site gets an error. Turns out the reply_url sent to Authorize.net (x_reply_url) is being sent as non-ssl (e.g. http://mysite.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response as a POST). However, this gets a 500 error because Magento is set to require SSL on the frontend. If I send a test post using (https://mysite.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response as a POST) it gets a 200 response. I'm looking at this by having turned on Debug in the DPM payment method and then viewing the file var/log/payment_authorizenet_directpost.log.

So I'm looking through all the code in app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet and have yet to pull out a section of code where it might be getting this non-ssl URL. And of course then answer the question of "Why isn't it pulling a secure URL instead?".

It looks like it originates possibly in the placeAction method of controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php.

I was hoping I might get some informed insight here as to whether I'm on the right track and how best to log or var_dump the appropriate variables (on my test site) to verify any changes.

Comment: Do you have access to x_reply_url that is being sent to Authorize.net? If so, try setting it to //mysite.com/... (leave off the 'http:').  Links like that will be used as either http or https, as required.

Comment: I haven't had the problem you're describing in Enterprise.  Have you thought about upgrading to 1.12?

Comment: seanbreeden: We are preparing to upgrade to site soon, but this has to be fixed before that. I'm looking at downloading 1.12 or 1.13 to review possible changes in the authorizenet Magento code. Thanks.

Comment: Patrick: Actually access to what sets the x_reply_url is exactly what I'm looking for. Still not sure if it is JS or PHP. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick the URL must be absolute and stand by itself. It is called up by the Authorize.Net payment gateway, and not in the context of a browser page, so // on its own will not work without the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. This appears to be a bug in the code for the authorize.net directpost method.

Modified file: app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php

Method: getRelayUrl

Old code:

```
return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK) . 'authorizenet/directpost_payment/response';
```

New code:

```
if(Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->isCurrentlySecure()) {
  return rtrim(Mage::getUrl('authorizenet/directpost', array('_secure' => true)),"/") .     '_payment/response';
} else {
  return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK) . 'authorizenet/directpost_payment/response';
}
```

This was in Magento Pro 1.11.1.0 (same code as Magento EE 1.11.1.0). I have not yet received access to any newer versions of Magento EE in order to see if this has been resolved in 1.12 or higher.

Comment: I'm using Magento CE 1.18 and it was still broken for me, your code fixed things for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Magento CE 1.9.2.4 - this fix was necessary for me as well. Additional information: don't forget to add the url https://www.shop.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response as Default Relay Response URL in authorize.net backend